# Localization based on country in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to localize the content sent back to the user based on the country they are viewing my app from meaning that their country code should be part of the request url. For example, if the user is in the US, all request URLs should be something like http://website.com/us/{controller}/{action}.

With that said, is there a way to identify the country of origin of the user and then modify the request URL by appending their country `Iso-2-Letter-Code` to that URL and then redirect the user with new URL. If the request URL has a country code, then this request modification should be bypassed.

I would prefer a solution that uses or creates an asp.net core middleware that i can attach to my HTTP request pipeline in Startup.cs or one that involves adding a new custom route to the default MVC routes.

Your help & ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did I answer your queries above? If yes, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing feature in .Net that you can know what is the origin. It's called [Culture Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8).

By default, each client will pass in a culture info or they can specify what is the current language/country they intended to use.

My suggestions is to allow client to specify the culture-info in the Header name call "Accept-Language". For example, I am in US and intended to use English, I would sent 'en-us' as part of my request inside the header.

Inside backend server, I would check against this header and set the culture-info appropriately.

```
 public class LanguageMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string LangenUS = "en-US";

    private readonly List<string> _supportedLanguages = new List<string> { LangenUS };

    private bool SetHeaderIfAcceptLanguageMatchesSupportedLanguage(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        foreach (var lang in request.Headers.AcceptLanguage)
        {
            if (_supportedLanguages.Contains(lang.Value))
            {
                SetCulture(request, lang.Value);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void SetCulture(HttpRequestMessage request, string lang)
    {
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Clear();
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue(lang));
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!SetHeaderIfAcceptLanguageMatchesSupportedLanguage(request))
        {
            // Whoops no localization found. Lets try Globalisation
            if (!SetHeaderIfGlobalAcceptLanguageMatchesSupportedLanguage(request))
            {
                // no global or localization found
                SetCulture(request, LangenUS);
            }
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }

    private bool SetHeaderIfGlobalAcceptLanguageMatchesSupportedLanguage(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        foreach (var lang in request.Headers.AcceptLanguage)
        {
            var globalLang = lang.Value.Substring(0, 2);
            if (_supportedLanguages.Any(t => t.StartsWith(globalLang)))
            {
                SetCulture(request, _supportedLanguages.FirstOrDefault(i => i.StartsWith(globalLang)));
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @hongguan, the current problem at hand is country-specific and not necessarily language-specific. Your suggested solution looks great but it does not address the question. Thanks for taking the time though, I appreciate your input on this.

Comment: hey, it's the same. If you notice on the culture-info, it is specifically design for your problem :"LanguageCode-CountryCode" : en-US

Comment: Quick question, when an ajax request is invoked from 2 separate countries e.g US & France in the front-end, will the server receive two separate culture-info's i.e (en-US, and fr-FR). If the answer is yes, that would make me very happy.

Comment: I just tested with a computer in Kenya and instead of getting en-KE, I got en-US. I think it's using the culture-info set in the requesting computer and most people's settings don't necessarily reflect their actual locale. 

Thanks for helping me brainstorm over this issue. I will mark this as accepted. If by any chance you come across another solution, please hit me up.

Comment: that's why most application design will ask for location permission and set the culture-info based on the country located. It is necessary for your use case. But anyway, culture-info is the way to go.

Comment: I guess I will have to request my users to give location access via javascript then append that to my request headers. Btw, I just thought of something, what if I use their IpAddress, then locate them using that. IP addresses are normally accurate country-wise assuming one is not using a VPN.

Comment: yes. that is another way but as you say, it is not very accurate as sometimes the application server is not located at the user origin country.